# How to reference a Rhino rhp from a Grasshopper ghe

Tags: c#, .net, grasshopper, rhino3d

When writing Grasshopper extensions in C#, I'd like to access symbols defined within my Rhino plugin.

A common example is that my plugin might attach custom UserData classes to objects, and I'd like to be able to access the members of that data later in Grasshopper.

In my specific example, I have a class MirrorData which is added to a set of Breps. I can set and get this from my rhino plugin.

The issue is that for my Grasshopper extension to know about MirrorData, I need to reference the rhino plugin from the grasshopper extension, but this isn't allowed since the rhino plugin outputs .rhp which can't be used as a valid reference.

I've found a workaround by referencing the temporary MirrorPlugin.dll in my plugin's obj folder from the grasshopper extension. But this doesn't seem to be the 'proper' approach.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The recommended approach is to make an assembly, that references RhinoCommon, that is shared between your Rhino plug-in and your Grasshopper component. In this shared assembly, add all of the functionality that you need in the other projects. If you need a sample that demonstrates this, see the following:

https://github.com/dalefugier/Platonics

In the future, you might want to post your Rhino development question on our Discourse discussion forum:

http://discourse.mcneel.com/

We tend to monitor this forum more diligently than others. ;-)

-- Dale

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note is that your rhino plugin does not have to be an rhp file. A dll works fine but I guess you lose the drag and drop install feature. I use a custom installer to install my plugin dll and grasshopper dll into the same directory. The grasshopper plugin is then able to access the rhino plugin no problem. I think that I only end up with one instance of the rhino plugin in memory but I've not verified this explicitly (in my case I don't care about multiple instances)